# Keyboard lag when starting gvim

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gvim

After I upgraded to 11.10, I've had a weird problem with gvim. Every time I start gvim, all my keyboard input to gvim is delayed by several seconds.

This problem usually goes away after attempting to use gvim for a while, but then appears again on new windows.

I'm running the gnome-classic desktop with ibus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround at [this blog](http://tots.1o24.org/gvim-problems-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/).

Using `gvim -f` doesn't have this problem, apparently, so aliasing `gvim` to `setsid /usr/bin/gvim -f` works. For bash, you can put

```
gvim(){ setsid /usr/bin/gvim -f "$@"; }
```

in your `.bashrc`.